# Improve your cv asking for things I already have

Tags: discussion, bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs, developer-story

My CV is telling me to improve my cv by making the following changes:

- Enter your full name
- Enter your email
- Add a location

[image]

All three things are already in my CV and have been in there since day one.  I am at 95% completion score on the CV (please remove this percentage as all it causes is problems for users, it has no meaning).

Comment: I'll have a look at the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a bug in the way we calculate CV completeness.

This is now fixed.

Thanks for your report!

Comment: There must be another issue, because now it is asking for the name of my project and a description in the open source section.  And I have both of those 2!  Should I file another bug report?

Comment: @JonH Yes, please. Thank you!

Comment: Gasser - Posted a new question about it.  Thanks!