# CV now asking for a project name and description already has it!

Tags: bug, stack-overflow-jobs, developer-story

I posted this earlier: [Improve your cv asking for things I already have](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323362/improve-your-cv-asking-for-things-i-already-have/323383?noredirect=1#comment345961_323383).
After validating the answer I have found that there is still another bug in the algorithm..

Now my CV is asking me to:

- Entered a name and description for each project

In which case my current cv already has a description and a name for the project listed.  Seems to still be a bug.

Comment: Is this related to developer story or to your CV?

Comment: Its tagged dev story

Comment: Sure, but you mention CV several times and the functionality appears to be CV-related... Tagging mistake?

Comment: I think it is the dev story sorry